# why request.security_lower_tf does work in the replay?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have the following code that works okay in real time when I am on 15 min timeframe and the code is supposed to get the data for the timeframe of 10.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay = false)

array_data = request.security_lower_tf(syminfo.tickerid, "10", ta.rsi(close,14))
array_data_last = array.size(array_data)>0?array.last(array_data):0
plot(array_data_last, color=color.aqua,linewidth=2)
```

[image: https://www.tradingview.com/x/f28ns6hV/]

However, when I try the `replay`, the code stops working and only shows zero

[image: https://www.tradingview.com/x/unnAozpv/]

Is there any way to fix this issue?

If I go down to 10 min time frame the code works fine again, but I like to see the results from the 15 min time frame.

Comment: This is known issue, will be fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be fixed by TV.